# Error in QComboBox if selections aren't changed

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a combobox which, when run, is setted up to current year and current month as in picture.

[image]

```
import sys
from time import strftime
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap


convert_number_month = {"1": "Gennaio", "2": "Febbraio", "3": "Marzo", 
"4": "Aprile", "5": "Maggio", "6": "Giugno", "7": "Luglio", "8": "Agosto", 
"9": "Settembre", "10": "Ottobre", "11": "Novembre", "12": "Dicembre"}

class MakeCombos(QtWidgets.QWidget):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.anno_in = None
    self.mese_in = None
    self.initUI(self)
    self.Data_For_Db()

def MeseSelected_func(self, text=None):  # +++
        self.mese_in = text

def AnnoSelected_func(self, text=None):  # +++
        self.anno_in = text


def initUI(self, Form):

    Form.setObjectName("Form")
    Form.resize(300, 300)

    self.work_Year_select = QtWidgets.QComboBox(Form)
    self.work_Year_select.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 140, 80, 20))
    self.work_Year_select.setObjectName("work_Year_select")
    self.work_Month_select = QtWidgets.QComboBox(Form)
    self.work_Month_select.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 140, 100, 21))
    self.work_Month_select.setObjectName("work_Month_select")
    self.work_Add_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
    self.work_Add_btn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 169, 70, 20))
    self.work_Add_btn.setObjectName("work_Add_btn")

    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    self.work_Year_select.addItems(['2017', '2018', '2019', '2020', '2021', '2022', '2023', '2024'])
    self.this_year = strftime("%Y")
    self.work_Year_select.setCurrentText(self.this_year)
    self.work_Year_select.currentTextChanged.connect(self.AnnoSelected_func)
    self.work_Month_select.addItems(
        ['Gennaio', 'Febbraio', 'Marzo', 'Aprile', 'Maggio', 'Giugno', 'Luglio', 'Agosto', 'Settembre', 'Ottobre',
         'Novembre', 'Dicembre'])
    self.this_month = strftime("%-m")
    self.this_month = convert_number_month[self.this_month]
    self.work_Month_select.setCurrentText(self.this_month)
    self.work_Month_select.currentTextChanged.connect(self.MeseSelected_func)
    self.work_Add_btn.setText(_translate("Library_main", "Select"))
    self.work_Add_btn.clicked.connect(self.Data_For_Db)

    
 def Data_For_Db(self):
        if self.mese_in == None or self.anno_in == None:
           print('Missing Selection')

        else: print("Its OK")
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
exe= MakeCombos()
exe.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

My problem is: if I press "Select" without changing both the values of "Anno" and "Mese" I get the error "SELEZIONE MANCANTE/Missing selection"
Which means: if i need to read data related to 2021 an Gennaio/Janaury I must click on another year AND another month then
return to the required values

I supposed that the shown values (2021 and Gennaio) were already active

Comment: You can try connecting the signal before setting the value for the comboboxes.

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: MeseSelected_func is only called when currentTextChanged (that is when the text *is* changed. So either set `self.mese_in = 'January'` in your class constructor, or (better imho) get the content of the combobox only when needed in Data_For_db with `self.Work_Month_select.currentText()` (and do not even have a variable self.mese_in at all).

Comment: @Demi-Lune. how can I get the content of the combobox when Im already in another class? Anyway I edited the code to have a mre

Comment: @steza please be more careful when entering code and always check the preview before posting. Read more about [formatting code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the name suggests, Qt signals that end with a `Changed` suffix are only emitted when the property *changes*.

In your case, this means that the connected functions will not be called on startup because you connected the signal **after** adding the items. Generally, if you want to be sure that the function gets called during initialization, you could connect the signal *before* adding items, since the text is empty by default, and as soon as the *first* item is added, QComboBox automatically changes the index to that.

Since you only need that data when you call `Data_For_Db`, there's absolutely no need to set instance attributes whenever the text changes, and you can just use [`combo.currentText()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#currentText-prop):

```
    def Data_For_Db(self):
        month = self.work_Month_select.currentText()
        year = self.work_Year_select.currentText()
        # ...
```

Some further (and partially unrelated) notes:

1. using `setCurrentText()` for a non editable combo box is not a good idea, and `setCurrentIndex()` should be always preferred;
2. using `strftime`, `convert_number_month` and then `setCurrentText()` is an *ugly* way to select the current month (and using a dictionary to get the month name is not a good approach); since the number and name of months are obviously known, get the current month number from `date.today().month` or `QDate.currentDate().month()` and subctract 1 for `setCurrentIndex()`;
3. avoid fixed geometries at any cost, and always use [layout managers](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) instead;
4. variable and function names should *never* be capitalized, as only classes and constants should;
5. don't try to imitate the behavior of files generated by pyuic, it's considered bad practice and usually leads to confusion; you can still use an `initUi` function if you want, but get rid of its `Form` argument, as it's completely useless;

Comment: @musicamente. Allow mw, just for this time, to reply to your notes. 1) will study the difference.2) The dictionary is used all around the project so... why don use it? and I need numerical value to access DB. 5) I agree and I face problems every time I try to use pyuic generated files is a mess. Thank you very much for your suggestions

Comment: #1 consider that a combo box is, first of all, an index based input (despite the fact that it usually contains text): it has a monodimensional data model that is accessed using integers, exactly like a list. While you *can* use strings to access its items, it's not advisable. Also note that you can add custom data to the items: `for m, month in enumerate(monthNames, 1): self.combo.addItem(month, str(m))` and directly access that with `self.combo.currentData()` if you need the numeric value. Have a look at [QLocale.monthName](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlocale.html#monthName) too.

Comment: #2 it's more about logic, readabiliy and extensibility (and, potentially, localization): using `strftime("%-m")` -> `convert_number_month[self.this_month]` is a very convoluted method; if you use that all around the project, just create 2 functions, one that returns the month name from a numeric (even str) input, and the other that just returns the *current*. It's more modular, and fare more easy and intuitive to read when you actually use it and to eventually improve/further implement in the future.

Comment: #5 those files should always be left alone, and never, **ever** modified for any reason. If you want to use a ui created in designer, read how to correctly use those files in the official guidelines about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html): in this way you only need to save the ui and use pyuic everytime you need to modify the ui, allowing you to keep the current state of your actual program. Note that ui files can also be automatically loaded using the `uic` module without using pyuic: in the `__init__` add `uic.loadUi('somefile.ui', self)`.